# PHP - Get all keys after the first

Tags: php, arrays

From an array in PHP for example:

```
array(
    [0] => "A",
    [1] => "B",
    [2] => "C",
    [3] => "D"
)
```

How can I get an array containing the keys after the fisrt one. So the example will be:

```
array(
    [0] => "B",
    [1] => "C",
    [2] => "D"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[array_shift](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) is a possibility.

```
$output = array_shift($input);
```

Answer (score 1):

[array_slice()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) is one way:

```
$result = array_slice($array, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`array_slice`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) returns a subsequence of an array.

```
array_slice($array, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array_shift($array);
```

[`array_shift`](http://php.net/array_shift) modifies the array as a reference. If you need the value that is shifted, simply assign it to a variable.

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/145056)**